# Removing undefined from MongoDB array

Tags: mongodb

I have added undefined values to array using script performed on a server side (Mongo version - 3.4.10).

Let's say I have document like

```
{
   "array" : ["a","b", undefined]
}
```

and I want to remove undefined element.

When I query it like this

```
find({"array" :  {$elemMatch : {$in : [null], $exists : true} }})
```

It returns above document - Mongo treats null and undefined as equal.

However, below update query is not removing element as expected (works fine for nulls)

```
update({} ,{ $pull : {"array" : {$in : [null]} }}, {multi : true})
```

It is also not possible to use undefined as math expression

```
InMatchExpression equality cannot be undefined
```

**Question:** How do you remove elements in such a situation?

Comment: Have you tried `db.collection.updateMany({}, {"$pull": { "array": undefined }});`?

Comment: @kadiii Added my answer below, check it out..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db.collection.update(
 {},
 {$pull: {"address.coord":{$type: 6}}},
 {multi:true}

)
```

Refer the [type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) & [pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operators for more details.
  It will remove all the `undefined` matches as per your requirement. If your document structure have nested arrays, use `$[]` positional operators.